# Como cambiar el tema a SweetAlert2 v9.x

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

he intentado cambiar el tema de mi sweetAlert2, pero no he tenido éxito.

Los siguientes archivos fueron extraídos de la pagina oficial de SweetAlert2, pero no puedo lograr que se cambie el tema, se queda con el default, he buscado como hacerlo, pero sale que solo basta con declarar el css y se cambia el tema, pero desconozco si es que hay que cambiar algun otro archivo o alguna parte donde indique que estoy utilizando x tema

Este es mi css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/sweetAlert2/css/borderless.css">
```

el cual es este css 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-borderless/borderless.css

y mi js

```
<script src="/sweetAlert2/js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
```

el cual es este js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Ya lo solucione, primero aclarar que el theme borderless no era lo que necesitaba ya que al abrir un mensaje de confirmacion, este se abre en pantalla completa (supongo que por ello el nombre), el punto es que logre cambiar al tema Dark, pero por alguna razon, al descargarlos desde jsDelivr no me carga el tema.

Por lo tanto lo que hice fue inspeccionar la pagina de sweetalert y sacar los archivos que necesitaba desde ahí (css del tema seleccionado y el js) y funciona perfectamente ahora

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]